# Resizing path of svg group

Tags: svg

**I would like to resize path around 20 pixels.**

SVG should be same size of 500 * 500, now the path width is 297 and height is 180.7. Now i need this path with width 277 and height 160.7 inside the previous path.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>Scale Paht Svg`**`enter code here`**`</h1>

<svg width="500" height="500">
    <path xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" stroke="#000000" d="M245.5,263.5l-148,179c0,0,287,4,297,0L245.5,263.5z"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to change your code like this:
The SVG canvas is 500 units / 500 units so you can use a viewBox attribute: `viewBox="0 0 500 500"`. Noe you can change the size of your SVG to 20/20 by adding `width="20" y="20`. Since the scaled down stroke would be very thin you need to add `vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"`. This way the stroke won't be scaled down.

```css
svg{border:1px solid;}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 500 500" width="20" y="20">
    <path vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" fill="none" stroke="#000000" d="M245.5,263.5l-148,179c0,0,287,4,297,0L245.5,263.5z"/>
</svg>
```

UPDATE

If you need the SVG canvas to be 500px / 500px but only this path to be 20/20px you can use SVG symbols:

```css
svg{border:1px solid;}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 500 500">
<symbol id="triangle" viewBox="0 0 500 500"> 
 <path  vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" fill="none" stroke="#000000" d="M245.5,263.5l-148,179c0,0,287,4,297,0L245.5,263.5z"/>
 </symbol>
  <use xlink:href="#triangle" width="20"  height="20" />
</svg>
```

### 2-ond UPDATE

The OP comments:

> SVG should be same size of 500 * 500, now the path width is 297 and height is 180.7. Now i need this path with width 277 and height 160.7 inside the previous path.

Next comes a code example :
Y hope this is what you need.

```html
<svg width="500" height="500">
  <symbol id="triangle" viewBox="97.5 263.5 297 180.78" > 
    <path id="test" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" stroke="#000000" d="M245.5,263.5l-148,179c0,0,287,4,297,0L245.5,263.5z"/>
  </symbol> 
  <use xlink:href="#triangle"/>
  <use xlink:href="#triangle" width="277" height="160.7" x="110.5" y="188.5"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: I would like to reduce the size of path 20 pixels.

Comment: Please explain me more: Do you need the SVG canvas to be 500px / 500px but only this path to be 20/20px?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I need for path only.

Comment: In this case you'll have to rewrite the code for the path. Can you explain what do you need it for? SVG stands for Scalable Vector Graphics. You can easily resize everything. But in this case your question is not clear. Please explain what do you need it for.

Comment: Thank you, Let me explain with example , SVG should be same size of 500 * 500, now the path width is 297 and height is 180.7. Now i need this path with width 277 and height 160.7 inside the previous path. If still my question is not clear let me know. Thanks in advance.